# Submodules of Noetherian modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$k(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a $k[x_i]_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$-module.
$k[x_i]_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a $k[x_i]_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$- submodule of $k(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$.

$k(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is noetherian.  So why isn't $k[x_i]_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ noetherian too?

I.e. why doesn't this contradict

> Soit M un A-module. Si M est noethérien, alors tout sous A-module de M est noethérien, tout quotient de M est noethérien et tout module de type fini sur M est noethérien.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not a nonexample:

$k(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is  noetherian as a $k(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$-module but not as a $k[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$-module, since ideals in an ascending chain of $k[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are $k[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$-submodules of $k(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: I was simply using the "answer my own question" tool under the "share your knowledge Q&A style".  I thought this was an instructive example on not just blindly applying the word noetherian.If this violates stackexchange rules, I would appreciate it if you  could show me a meta post showing me what is wrong with this.